# Flutter insert List of arrays to SQFlite database without repetition

Tags: flutter, sqlite, math, sqflite

I'm new to flutter and I'm practicing flutter and I want prepopulated database on button click I want to insert 10 data at once. The code is working but it is inserting in a repetition manner i.e. 1 will be inserted 2 or three times but I want to insert 10 rows of data in the database without repetition here is my Model:

```
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';

import 'dart:convert';

Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Welcome {
  Welcome({
    required this.tfModel,
  });

  List<TfModel> tfModel;

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
    tfModel: List<TfModel>.from(json["TfModel"].map((x) => TfModel.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "TfModel": List<dynamic>.from(tfModel.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}



class TfModel {
  TfModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.content,
    required this.moredesc,
   
  });

  int id;
  String content;
  String moredesc;

  final isFavorite = false.obs;

  factory TfModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TfModel(
    id: json["id"],
    content: json["content"],
    moredesc: json["moredesc"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "content": content,
    "moredesc": moredesc,
  };
}
```

database Helper for insetting Data to the database:

```
newClient(TfModel newClient) async {
    final db = await database;

    var raw = await db.rawInsert(
        "INSERT Into QList (id,content,moredesc)"
            " VALUES (?,?,?)",
        [newClient.id,  newClient.content, newClient.moredesc]);
    return raw;
  }
```

On my homepage, I have created model data and when the user clicks the start button data starts to be inserted into the database.
**onPressed  action on homepage.dart**

```
onPressed: () async {
          print(testClients.length);
          for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            TfModel rnd = testClients[testClients.length-1];
            try {
              await DBProvider.instance.newClient(rnd);
            }
            on DatabaseException catch (e){
              print("Database Exception");
              print(e);
            }
         
          }
         


         
        },
```

testClient array is below:

```
List<TfModel> testClients = [
    TfModel(id: 1,
        content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 2,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 3,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
         TfModel(id: 4,
        content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 5,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 6,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
         TfModel(id: 7,
        content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 8,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
    TfModel(id: 9,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
     TfModel(id: 10,
         content: "Test",
        moredesc: "Test Data"),
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Future<void> insertFeeds(List<s.Feeds> feeds) async {
final db = await banco;
var list = [];
feeds.forEach((element) => list.add(element.toMap()));

await db!.rawInsert(
    'INSERT INTO feeds(editorial_id,feed_id,remessa,total_comments,total_reactions,user_reaction,texto,last_update) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    list);
```

}

Comment: add multiples values on database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).